# daily sales and qty of users report in mysql+PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, report

I don't know how show the quantity of users(pacientes) per day the admin (doctor) watch it..
I have this daily report which works in print me the total sales in each day but if I need to show the qty of user(pacientes) he saw(like 10 pacientes) the code print 2000 or many more..

can you help me with this?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Fecha</th>
          <th>Total Pacientes vistos</th>
          <th>Total diario</th>                                 
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <? 
                include 'config.php';
                $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DATE(start) AS date, SUM(id_paciente) AS total_pacientes, SUM(honorario) AS total_diario
                FROM CITAS WHERE start >= CURDATE() AND start < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY start ASC");
                $sql->execute();
                while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
            <td class="center"><? echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><? echo $row['total_pacientes']; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><? echo $row['total_diario']; ?></td>                 
        </tr>   <? } ?>                          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**table CITAS**

- **start**  datetime
- **honorario**  varchar
- **id_paciente**  int

I need the report show like this:

date(fecha)--------total_user(total de pacientes)-----total_sales(total diario)

- 10-junio-2013----------25---------------------------------650.00
- 09-junio-2013----------10---------------------------------250.00
- 08-junio-2013----------15---------------------------------375.00

But right now show it like this:

date(fecha)--------total_user(total de pacientes)-----total_sales(total diario)

- 10-junio-2013----------65725---------------------------------650.00
- 09-junio-2013----------34510---------------------------------250.00
- 08-junio-2013----------49815---------------------------------375.00

id_paciente have 17,000 users and is a FK of table PACIENTES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
SUM(id_paciente) AS total_pacientes
```

You don't want to sum the ids.  You want to count them.  Replace it with:

```
count(id_paciente) AS total_pacientes
```

Comment: Thank you that is the right sentence...if I need to show monthly report..What I need to change in the code?